# Using video.js with mutiple subtitles and words that can be clicked

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I would like to enquire about the different possibilities of using subtitles with the video.js player.
We would like to implement two things on our web site:

1- The ability for the user to choose a subtitle OR two subtitles at the same time, for example he would have english and spanish subtitles appearing above each other at the same time. This is a common feature available in programs such as VLC, KMplayer, etc. but doesn't seem to be possible with web video players.

2- The ability to make all words of the subtitle/caption file clickable, which means that every word of the subtitle would become a link.

If this not possible by default, can you tell if it's easily feasible and in which direction we should think at in order to develop it?

Thank you!